# autocomplete is not working for my html page

Tags: html

```
<label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
<input name="firstName" type="text" autocomplete="given-name">

<label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
<input name="lastName" type="text" autocomplete="family-name">

<label for="MiddleName">Middle Name:</label>
<input name="MiddleName" type="text" autocomplete="additional-name">

<label for="NickName">Nick Name:</label>
<input name="NickName" type="text" autocomplete="nickname">

<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input name="email" type="email" autocomplete="email">

<button>Submit</button>
```

---

```
button,
input
    {
    display:block;
    margin: 4px;
    }
```

for testing chrome v 108 with all auto-filling settings turned on,
I tried changing the various autocomplete values in html code
like:autocomplete="family-name" or "given-name" etc etc but still autocomplete is not working

Comment: autocomplete="on"

Comment: so how do I change in <input name="firstName" type="text" autocomplete="given-name" >

Answer (score -2, accepted):

refer example in : [mdn autocomplete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)
Also refer quote in link:

> Note: In order to provide autocompletion, user-agents might require // elements to:

Have a name and/or id attribute
Be descendants of a  element
The form to have a submit button

```css
button,
    input
    {
        display:block;
        margin: 4px;
    }
```

```html
 
      <form id="myGeeks">


    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input name="firstName" type="text" autocomplete="given-name">

    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input name="lastName" type="text"  autocomplete="family-name">

    <label for="MiddleName">Middle Name:</label>
    <input name="MiddleName" type="text" autocomplete="additional-name">

    <label for="NickName">Nick Name:</label>
    <input name="nickName" type="text" autocomplete="nickname">

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input name="email" type="email"  autocomplete="email">

    <button>Submit</button>

  </form>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).